# android.view.InflateException : Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout

Tags: android

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout"

I am getting this error can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

We'd need a little more of your output to know for sure but my bet is your layout is lacking either layout_width or layout_height. Can you please post a little more extended context for your exceptions (a few lines before, a few lines after the line you already posted) ?

Comment: i agree, this is likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i faced,

At one of my inflate view i getting "android.view.InflateException", because
i am using image of 1200x1200. I conveted it to 100x100 and now it working.

Answer (score 0):

You may try removing tags like `android:divider` in the XML file.